# Node AWS command not found in Jenkins script

Tags: node.js, bash, jenkins, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to push my **React App build** to an **S3 bucket** from **Jenkins/BlueOcean** plugin.

But the `aws` command doesn't work inside of the Jenkins script.

This is what my script is doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
set -x
npm install -g aws-sdk
set +x

set -x
aws
echo $PATH
set +x
```

Here's the output:
[image]

The `npm install` works just fine, even `npm start` (to start my react server on localhost). In my development environment I can type `aws` without any errors.

I'm guessing it's an issue with the `PATH`? I've only been able to find issues regarding `npm` not working, but that works fine for me.

Why can't the script find `aws` as a command? How do I fix that?

Comment: What does your  $PATH say?

Comment: What do you get in your dev environment when you run `command -v aws`?

Comment: I guess your `aws` in your development not from your `npm install`. Maybe that's installed by `pip`. Please try `which aws` on your development and your server.

Comment: Thanks for you responses, I'll be posting a solution within the next day or two. I was able to figure out what was going on once I got a better grasp of what was happening with Docker, Jenkins, Nodejs, and BlueOcean.. I spent well over 36 hours trying to figure this out.